# Unable to understand CBCBlockCipherMac.update

Tags: encryption, bouncycastle

Am presently trying to port a java code to object-c. I however came accross CBCBlockCipherMac.update and CBCBlockCipherMac.doFinal in the code but don't understand what this methods do and how they work. The point of confusion is where a 21 character string was converted to bytes and passed to this method and the output was a [4]bytes string. Someone please explain to me how this methods work. Sample code is attached below. Please explain in step what is going in this method:

```
public String getMyMac("Thisstringis21inlength")
     {
    byte [] macKey = {0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10}
         byte[] macBytes = new byte[4];
         CBCBlockCipherMac macCipher = new CBCBlockCipherMac(new DESedeEngine());
         DESedeParameters keyParameters = new DESedeParameters(macKey);
         DESedeEngine engine = new DESedeEngine();
         engine.init(true, keyParameters);
         macCipher.init(keyParameters);
         byte[] macDataBytes = macData.getBytes(); 
         macCipher.update(macDataBytes, 0, macData.length());
         macCipher.doFinal(macBytes, 0);
         byte[] encodedMacBytes = Hex.encode(macBytes);
         String mac = new String(encodedMacBytes);
         return mac;
     }
```

Comment: This code will fail if macData contains any characters that don't fit into a single byte, or if the platform encoding is different than expected. Moreover, it will simply calculate an incorrect MAC if either failure mode is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it uses the 3DES in CBC mode for generating a [message authentication code (MAC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code). 
The MAC consists of the first four bytes of the last encrypted block. The input is padded with zeros if it does not fit the block size.